# How is a Docker container used in AWS Batch? And what is the maximum vCPUs exactly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am new to AWS Batch  and the description was not quite clear sometimes and I need several clarifications.

First, what is exactly the maximum vCPUs for?  Is is the maximum number of CPUs that each job can take . or maximum number of CPUs that all jobs can take in total?

And I linked a Docker image to my job definition and I will submit many jobs in parallel through AWS Batch. Does each job have its own container or do all jobs under the same job definition share the container? (In other words, do the jobs running in parallel share the files in the same container?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> First, what is exactly the maximum vCPUs for? Is is the maximum number
>   of CPUs that each job can take or maximum number of CPUs that all jobs
>   can take in total?

On a compute environment, Maximum vCPUs is the total sum of vCPUs that can be run at the same time. For example, with a max 16 vCPUs, Batch could spin up to 2 instances with 8 vCPUs each or up to 1 instance with 16 vCPUs.

> And I linked a Docker image to my job definition and I will submit
>   many jobs in parallel through AWS Batch. Does each job have its own
>   container or do all jobs under the same job definition share the
>   container?

Each job has its own container with its own filesystem. You might be able to get jobs running on the same instance to share files using volumes or mount points in the job definition, but that wouldn't fit how Batch was designed to be used since you have no guarantee of what jobs will be running on the same instance.